# mix variables/results between chunks in knitr defined in different languages?

Tags: python, r, knitr

`Language engines` is a great `knitr` feature . We can use any languages in knitr, including but not limited to R. *But what if I want to use results/variable defined in a one chunck , in another chunck either with the same language or in another language (more sexy option)?*

Better to explain my idea with some code. Here I define 4 chunks, 2 in **python** and 2 in **R**.

First I define a variable `x` in python:

````
## I define engien path explicitly here (TODO: set it globally)
```{r,engine='python',engine.path='C:/Anaconda/python.exe' }
x = 1
print x
```
## 1
````

Now Try to use x in new python chunck:

````
```{r,engine='python',engine.path='C:/Anaconda/python.exe' }
x = x +1
print x

```
````

No error but amazing result, looks like x is NULL here. Now if I Try to use x in new R chunck:

````
```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
x +1
y = 2
```
## Error: object 'x' not found
````

I get an error. Now if I try to use y in new R chunk and it works fine. the r engine can use variable defined in the previous R chunck. Note this doesn't work with python.

````
```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
y+3
```
## [1] 5
````

Why there is  difference in behavior between R and python here? Is it structural due to R scoping rules or just a future not already implemented in knitr? or maybe a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the documented behaviour.

see http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/

> Except engine='R' (default), all chunks are executed in separate
>   sessions, so the variables cannot be directly shared. If we want to
>   make use of objects created in previous chunks, we usually have to
>   write them to files (as side effects). For the bash engine, we can use
>   Sys.setenv() to export variables from R to bash (example)

Comment: @agstudy Ladies and gentlemen, the current engine design is far from satisfactory and I definitely need help: https://github.com/yihui/runr I have [got Julia working in knitr](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/F78PBMIamwk), and I guess Python should be easier than Julia to be incorporated into R? The basic idea is to communicate through sockets or fifo. You are very welcome to be co-author this package.

Answer (score 1):

You could put something in a startup (`PYTHONSTARTUP`) file for python. An elaborate startup file can export all known variables in a file when exiting leveraging `atexit`.

Here is a recipe that prints all new globals:

```
>>> import atexit
>>> def list_globals(known_globals=globals().keys()):
...     new_globals = set(globals().keys())
...     new_globals -= set(known_globals)
...     for key in new_globals:
...        print '%s=%s' % (key, globals()[key])
... 
>>> atexit.register(list_globals)
<function list_globals at 0x107140e60>
>>> del list_globals
>>> del atexit
>>>
```

Here is an example session after the above code has been run.

```
>>> 
>>> def foo():
...    a  = 1
... 
>>> b = 2
>>> ^D
b=2
foo=<function foo at 0x107140d70>
```

You could instead use a file / socket / message queue / etc.